# Is is possible to run Java application in Hardware

Tags: java

Recently, I had a question like whether we can use java to programme the hardware...

I answered them like, to run java application we need JVM. So we can't use java to program the hardware...

But, I came to know, it is wrong...

But I don't understand clearly, how to install a jvm inside the hardware... how to run java application in hardware ...

Please clarify my doubt and if possible give me some example applications working in hardware...

Thanks

Comment: You probably need a native compiler for java for whatever platform you're supporting. Use Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=java+native+compiler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not?

The most reasonable parsing of "install jvm inside hardware" is to install software - the most common way to create a JVM.

However, there is nothing stopping you from building hardware that conforms to the JVM specs.

Here are some links:

1. [The Java Virtual Machine in Hardware](http://ti.tuwien.ac.at/rts/teaching/courses/jvmhw/)
2. [A Hardware Implementation of the Java Virtual Machine](http://www.hotchips.org/archives/hc8/2_Mon/HC8.S4/HC8.4.3.pdf)

Comment: Is this something that goes to dependent on platform right. It will be non portable. Am i right ?

Comment: The JVM isn't portable, but the bytecode is, no different to trying to install a Windows JVM on a Solaris box.

Answer (score 3):

A few links:

- [Oracle embedded java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/overview/index.html) (not sure if thats what you mean)
- [JOP](http://www.jopdesign.com/) : JVM on FPGA
- IBM [Liquid Metal](https://researcher.ibm.com/researcher/view_project.php?id=122) project

Answer (score 1):

There are JVM implementations for many different platforms. I like the one for lego mindstorms, you only need to flash the controller with the appropriate firmware and there you go.